# spring-boot 2.3.6, how to set UUID representation for mongo?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I'm trying to upgrade to spring-boot 2.3.6. I'm using spring-data MongoRepositories, no difrect calls to MongoClient or MongoClient.

Getting exception:

```
Caused by: org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: The uuidRepresentation has not been specified, so the UUID cannot be encoded.
    at org.bson.codecs.UuidCodec.encode(UuidCodec.java:72)
    at org.bson.codecs.UuidCodec.encode(UuidCodec.java:37)
    at org.bson.codecs.EncoderContext.encodeWithChildContext(EncoderContext.java:91)
    at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.writeValue(DocumentCodec.java:198)
    at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.writeMap(DocumentCodec.java:212)
    at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.encode(DocumentCodec.java:154)
    at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.encode(DocumentCodec.java:45)
```

Tried to customize

```java
@Bean
    public MongoClientSettingsBuilderCustomizer mongoDBDefaultSettings() {
        return builder -> {
            builder.uuidRepresentation(UuidRepresentation.JAVA_LEGACY);
        };
    }
```

doesn't help, same exception.

What is the right way to customize UUID codec in spring-boot 2.3.6?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

On Spring Boot application.properties simply inform:

```
spring.data.mongodb.uuid-representation=standard
```

Answer (score 4):

This can happen when you have a plain `MongoClient` bean defined, e.g.:

```
@Bean
public MongoClient mongoClient() {
    return MongoClients.create(MongoClientSettings.builder().build());
}
```

You use the `MongoClientSettingsBuilderCustomizer` to customize the auto-configured `MongoClient`. (Note, for later versions of Spring Boot, no customization is needed if the auto-configured `MongoClient` is used, because by default, as of Spring Boot 2.4.2, `MongoProperties` sets the UUID representation to `JAVA_LEGACY`.)

Per the [doc](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/b631fa140593ae91308d5a8f85701d6dda2a5324/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-docs/src/main/asciidoc/spring-boot-features.adoc):

> The auto-configured MongoClient is created using MongoClientSettings.
> To fine-tune its configuration, declare one or more
> MongoClientSettingsBuilderCustomizer beans. Each will be called in
> order with the MongoClientSettings.Builder that is used to build the
> MongoClientSettings.

If you need to have a custom `MongoClient`, you can set the UUID representation explicitly, e.g.:

```
@Bean
public MongoClient mongoClient() {
    return MongoClients.create(MongoClientSettings.builder()
               .uuidRepresentation(UuidRepresentation.JAVA_LEGACY)
               .build());
}
```

Comment: I dont understand. "This can happen [with] a plan MongoClient", but also "no customization is needed if the auto-configured MongoClient is used". Don't those statements conflict?

Comment: Updated to be more clear. I.e. Customizer is intended for auto-configured mongoClient, and if using later versions of SB, none is needed to set JAVA_LEGACY. Furthermore, OP is explicitly configuring the mongoClient, so the added Customizer is overridden/not used.

Answer (score 3):

For MongoDB version 4.3 or later, this is the fix which works for me.

```
MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
     .uuidRepresentation(UuidRepresentation.STANDARD)
     .build();
```