# Using MongoClient to read UUID written to with Spring Data

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data

I am having trouble reading UUID values written to a MongoDB collection with Spring Data MongoDB. For UUID `ca119807-967a-46df-b659-f0e5e4163a28` the value in the database is `_id : Binary('30Z6lgeYEcooOhbk5fBZtg==', 3)`.

This is how I am using Spring Data MongoDB to write UUIDs to the database:

```
@Document("foos")
class Foo {

@Id
private UUID uuid;
...
```

After fetching the same document with `com.mongodb.client.MongoClient`, I am able to access a field of type `org.bson.types.Binary`. It then looks like this:

[image]

This is how I am instantiating the variables listed above:

```
Binary id = doc.get("_id", Binary.class);
String base64String = Base64.encodeBase64String(id.getData());
```

I am not able to convert this value back to the original UUID. Passing the `byte[]` to `java.util.UUID#nameUUIDFromBytes` produces results that are nothing like the original UUID.

**How can I convert the `byte[]` in `org.bson.types.Binary` to UUID?**

I managed to use [Studio 3T](https://studio3t.com/download/) to read UUID values. For this, I had to change Legacy UUID Encoding to "Legacy Java Encoding". Before I did that, I was seeing the same UUID values as the ones I am getting from `java.util.UUID#nameUUIDFromBytes`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BSON binary subtype 3 is the legacy UUID format.  The legacy byte ordering was not defined, and so each client language was free to order the bytes in whatever way made sense to that language's implementation.

The base64 data `30Z6lgeYEcooOhbk5fBZtg==` in hex is:

```
df46 7a96 0798 11ca 283a 16e4 e5f0 59b6
```

If you compare that with the original UUID `ca119807-967a-46df-b659-f0e5e4163a28` you may notice that the first half of the hexadecimal:

```
df46 7a96 0798 11ca
```

is the reverse order of the first half of the UUID:

```
ca119807-967a-46df
```

Likewise for the second half:

```
283a 16e4 e5f0 59b6
b659-f0e5e4163a28
```

MongoDB Java driver's [org.bson.UuidRepresentation](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.5/javadoc/org/bson/UuidRepresentation.html) enum gives an inkling to the problem, it has possible values:

```
C_SHARP_LEGACY
JAVA_LEGACY
PYTHON_LEGACY
STANDARD
```

The peculiar encoding above is the JAVA_LEGACY format.

For how to specify which to use, see [spring-boot 2.3.6, how to set UUID representation for mongo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64958563/spring-boot-2-3-6-how-to-set-uuid-representation-for-mongo)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Joe's answer I was able to use utilities from `org.mongodb:bson:423` to decode JAVA_LEGACY bytes:

```
import org.bson.Document;
import org.bson.UuidRepresentation;
import org.bson.conversions.Bson;
import org.bson.internal.UuidHelper;
import org.bson.types.Binary;

(...)

result.map(document -> {
Binary id = document.get("_id", Binary.class);
byte[] data = id.getData();
byte type = id.getType();
return UuidHelper.decodeBinaryToUuid(data, type, 
        UuidRepresentation.JAVA_LEGACY);
}) (...)
```

The result is then the same UUID value as the one persisted with Spring Data MongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that java uuid converted into another uuid in mongo driver. So i write this code, for find the java uuid into mongodb:

```
import org.bson.UuidRepresentation;
import org.bson.codecs.Codec;
import org.bson.codecs.EncoderContext;
import org.bson.codecs.UuidCodec;
import org.bson.json.JsonWriter;

import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.UUID;

public class ConverterUuid {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Example
        createFindByUuidInCollection("efbc75d6-0402-4a98-98db-82669b65dba7", "customers");
        //result
        //db.customers.findOne({_id: new BinData(3, 'mEoCBNZ1vO+n22WbZoLbmA==')})
    }

    public static void createFindByUuidInCollection(String uuid, String collection) {
        String binaryId = getBinaryId(uuid);
        System.out.printf("db.%s.findOne({_id: new BinData(3, '%s')})", collection, binaryId);
    }

    public static String getBinaryId(String uuid) {
        UUID convertedUuid = UUID.fromString(uuid);
        EncoderContext encoderContext = EncoderContext.builder().build();
        Codec codec = new UuidCodec(UuidRepresentation.JAVA_LEGACY);
        JsonWriter jsonWriter = new JsonWriter(new StringWriter());
        encoderContext.encodeWithChildContext(codec, jsonWriter, convertedUuid);
        return jsonWriter.getWriter().toString().replaceAll("\\{\"\\$binary\": \\{\"base64\": \"", "")
                .replaceAll("\", \"subType\": \"03\"}}", "");
    }
}
```