# NoSuchMethodError: com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings$Builder.uuidRepresentation

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I've tried to get **up spring-boot** version from 2.1.1.RELEASE **to 2.3.8.RELEASE** and got error "Caused by: java.lang.**NoSuchMethodError**: com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings$Builder.**uuidRepresentation**(Lorg/bson/UuidRepresentation;)Lcom/mongodb/MongoClientSettings$Builder"

My application consists of several modules and one of them has a dependency on a customed 'import-export' service.  This service uses Mongo db while my application uses postgree db. When I run mvn dependency:tree, I see 'mongo' is mentioned only here:

```
    [INFO] +- ....export-import-lib-node:jar:0.2.3-springboot-2.3.5:compile
    [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb:jar:3.0.6.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:2.3.6.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |  |  \- org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-core:jar:4.0.5:compile
    [INFO] |  |     \- org.mongodb:bson:jar:4.0.5:compile
    [INFO] |  \- org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:jar:3.8.2:compile
```

Before version changes there were:

```
    [INFO] +- .....export-import-lib-node:jar:0.2.4:compile
    [INFO] |  \- org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb:jar:2.1.3.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |     +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:2.1.3.RELEASE:compile
    [INFO] |     \- org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:jar:3.8.2:compile
```

I've tried to add dependencies

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>bson</artifactId>
    <version>4.4.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongodb-driver-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.4.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
    <version>4.4.2</version>
</dependency>
```

but got the same error on running the application on Tomcat server.

Could you advice me what should I do to fix this error?
Thank you.

**Update:**
Added

```
@Bean
public MongoClient mongoClient() {
    return MongoClients.create(MongoClientSettings.builder()
            .uuidRepresentation(UuidRepresentation.JAVA_LEGACY)
            .build());
}
```

but still have the same error " Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.mongodb.client.MongoClient]: Factory method 'mongoClient' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings$Builder.uuidRepresentation(Lorg/bson/UuidRepresentation;)Lcom/mongodb/MongoClientSettings$Builder;"

Comment: Could be possible that you are missing other logs? maybe the initialization of uuidRepresentation? maybe this could be hepfull
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64958563/spring-boot-2-3-6-how-to-set-uuid-representation-for-mongo)https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64958563/spring-boot-2-3-6-how-to-set-uuid-representation-for-mongo

Comment: Hi. What logs do you mean? I look at logs which tomcat provides. Could you clarify where should I look for other logs? Thank you for the link to another ticket but the answers from it doesn't help.

Comment: I got the same error. Did u found the solution yet?

Comment: It seems like spring boot picked com.mongodb:mongo-java-driver instead of mongodb-driver-sync

Comment: Oh hey I got it worked now by removing com.mongodb:mongo-java-driver from the external lib

Answer (score 0):

Try following dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.12.2</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongodb-driver -->

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
  <artifactId>mongodb-driver</artifactId>
  <version>3.6.3</version>
  <exclusions>
               <exclusion>
                   <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId> <!-- Exclude Project-E from Project-B -->
                   <artifactId>bson</artifactId>
               </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
  <artifactId>mongodb-driver-core</artifactId>
  <version>3.11.0</version>
</dependency>
```